# Android - Buttons in Layout is being shown different on devices

Tags: android-layout

There are 8 buttons from top to bottom on my layout.

When i run .apk in my device, it is shown good. But when i run same .apk on an old android device, last 2 buttons is not shown. they dont squeeze on display

Please,  help me.

Comment: Can you please upload your xml layout file?

Answer (score 0):

Give equal weights to all buttons and set height and width of all buttons as wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Ad scrollview to your buttons.It is because the screen is small.